# Incorrect Street Number from HERE Geocoding API Rest request

Tags: here-api

We send this URL to HERE Rest API and the result gives an incorrect **Street Number**. Since we provide the **Street Number** correctly we assume it will be correct in the result.  Anybody knows why ?

[HERE Request Test](https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=ruQJLAz7S34BzGnTBgiA&app_code=zpN9z9-vk54NtXX_sWFbMg&searchtext=57%20Gaston-Tessier,%20Paris,%20FRA,%20%20+75019)

As you can see in this image, you have the requested address and the suggested address from HERE.  It corrected the postal code and added the state which is good but we don't understand about the **Street Number** being different.

[image: Example]

Here's the real location on Google Map :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is missing info for housenumber 57 for this street in HERE database so it suggest an alternative which is 18.

You should report it in mapcreator.here.com

Comment: I don't see where in mapcreator.here.com you can report such problem.  I see a map and I looked at all the options I have but I don't see and report problem option.  Can you lead me to the right direction ?

Comment: Ok I found it.  First time after registering the buton for Customer Ticket wasn't there but after leaving and going back I saw the button.  Thank you

Comment: You’re welcome ! It will take a few weeks to go through moderation and visible in the REST API though. Have a coffee meanwhile !